# SQL select only items that happen after but not also before a certain date

Tags: mysql

I have a table in SQL that contains People's IDs, codes and entry dates for each code. 
Table X:

```
PERSON_ID  CODE  ENTRY_DATE
1            A   2017-12-03
1            C   2016-01-13
1            C   2009-05-11
2            B   2007-03-25
2            F   2018-01-18
3            G   2003-04-09
```

And another table that contains the person_id and reference dates for each person. 
Table Y:

```
PERSON_ID   REF_DATE
1          2015-07-18
2          2017-06-17
3          2002-10-06
```

What I want to do is for each person select rows from table X for which codes happened after REF_DATE in TABLE Y but the CODE itself didn't also occur before REF_DATE. For Example, in the case of person 1, the codes that happened after 2015-07-18 are A (2017-12-03) and the first C (2016-01-13). But Since C also occurred before REF_DATE (2015-07-18) in 2009-05-11, C is not to be selected.

This is just an example, the actual tables have millions of rows and thousands of different codes so I can't manually type codes etc. 
the expected result of the query in this example should be:

```
PERSON_ID  CODE  ENTRY_DATE
1            A   2017-12-03
2            F   2018-01-18
3            G   2003-04-09
```

Any idea how to code that in SQL ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you post up a fiddle of same?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could limit the results within JOIN clause

Comment: Sorry strawberry I’m relatively new here , can you clarify what you meant ?

Comment: @Strawberry mean something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/050edcd/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you join both tables so you have `REF_DATE` then filter the rows to get only the ones after `REF_DATE`, but also make sure doesnt exist any row before that date with that code.

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/050edcd/5)

```
SELECT X.`PERSON_ID`, X.`CODE`, X.`ENTRY_DATE`, Y.`REF_DATE`
FROM TableX X
JOIN TableY Y
  ON X.`PERSON_ID` = Y.`PERSON_ID`
WHERE   X.`ENTRY_DATE` > Y.`REF_DATE`
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM TableX 
                   WHERE TableX.`PERSON_ID` = X.`PERSON_ID`
                     AND TableX.`CODE`= X.`CODE`
                     AND TableX.`ENTRY_DATE` <  Y.`REF_DATE`
                  )
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| PERSON_ID | CODE |           ENTRY_DATE |             REF_DATE |
|-----------|------|----------------------|----------------------|
|         1 |    A | 2017-12-03T00:00:00Z | 2015-07-18T00:00:00Z |
|         2 |    F | 2018-01-18T00:00:00Z | 2017-06-17T00:00:00Z |
|         3 |    G | 2003-04-09T00:00:00Z | 2002-10-06T00:00:00Z |
```